# Magento 2 : product quantity increasing automatically

Tags: magento2, product, cron, quantity, magento2.4.0

I am using magento 2.4.1, the issue is randomly my product's quantity is increasing, it automatically increments the quantity after some time. I tried to keep eye on few products and found that each products increment was different. I checked in logs also but none were generated.

i check somewhere and found that "sales_clean_orders" cron is the reason behind this. but even after disable the cron my product quantity is still increasing.

does anyone know what exactly "sales_clean_orders" cron do to product quantity?

Answer (score 1):

Cron `sales_clean_orders` - **Cleans Expired Orders**

First Run these CLI Commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset

indexer:reindex
```

Then Keep an Check If Product Qty Increases.

**If Yes** - Can you see any canceled orders with those products? As an Quick Fix (Which is Never Recommended), You can comment out the **cron** listed in

`vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/crontab.xml`

**Run**

```
php bin/magento cron:remove

php bin/magento cron:install -f
```

In the mean time keep checking, If you are using any Custom Payment Method & had an Observer

1. **order_cancel_after**
2. **sales_order_save_after**
3. **sales_order_state_change_before**

May be there is some buggy code there.

**Check the screenshot for more details**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See here, at our site it had to do with discount rules:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16779

The sales_clean_orders cron could not cancel the order and tries it each hour. But it actually does increase the stock level each time it tries...